# unable to install spatialEco in r studio

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, spatial

I am trying to install spatialEco in R

The error that was given to me is below:

```
    > install.packages("spatialEco", type = "source")
also installing the dependencies ‘units’, ‘sf’, ‘rgeos’

configure: error: in 
 `/private/var/folders/j6/bzjmvjns0_92545t_gbjkgcr0000gn
/T/Rtmp31qTqh/R.INS 
TALL2a7c4e9818c7/units':
configure: error: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------
 Configuration failed because libudunits2.so was not found. Try 
installing:
* deb: libudunits2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
* rpm: udunits2-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
* brew: udunits (OSX)

 See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘units’
* removing ‘/Users/anon/anaconda3/envs/abc/lib/R/library/units’
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
* removing ‘/Users/anon/anaconda3/envs/abc/lib/R/library/rgeos’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgeos’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘units’ is not available for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/Users/anon/anaconda3/envs/abc/lib/R/library/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘sf’, ‘rgeos’ are not available for package 
 ‘spatialEco’
  * removing ‘/Users/anon/anaconda3/envs/abc/lib/R/library/spatialEco’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘spatialEco’ had non-zero exit status
```

Is there a way to get spatialEco install on my device?

Comment: According to error message, it is obvious that there is a dependency missing. Assuming your os to be mac, you should try to install udunits. I don't have experience in mac os, you should figure it out how to do it.

Comment: I tried installing the dependencies one by one, it doesn't work...

Comment: Sometimes the problem will be related to versions... Different versions of dependencies/libraries can cause issues. You've to check dependence for that package and dependencies. I've faced such problem many times with versions in R.  It would be better if you share error/warnings showed, and with versions of packages. If not me, someone else may suggest solution.

Comment: Managed to solve it by upgrading Sierra to High Sierra and it works.